# .htaccess: правила верхнего каталога

Tags: php, .htaccess, поддомены

Приветствую!
Возник вопрос. В корне сайта в файле .htaccess прописываю следующие строчки для запрета выполнения скриптов:

```
RemoveHandler .php .cgi .fcgi .pl .fpl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .shtm .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .asp .jsp
RemoveType php
```

Все срабатывает, но если я добавлю в папку поддомена файл .htaccess с другим содержанием

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php .cgi .fcgi .pl .fpl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .shtm .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .asp .jsp
```

то вызванный файл из этой папки сработает, как php файл.
Соответственно вопрос: что нужно сделать, чтобы файлы .htaccess, расположенные в определенных папках, игнорировались. Папок много, вида s1, s2, s3... s100.

Comment: php 6 никогда не будет, за пятой версией будет сразу седьмая.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `AllowOverride None` в настройках httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride None
  RemoveHandler .php .cgi .fcgi .pl .fpl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .shtm .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .asp .jsp
  RemoveType php

</Directory>
```

Тогда файлы .htaccess  перестанут работать.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы через htaccess, т.к. нет доступа к root.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать это в .htaccess.

Comment: Это приведет к Internal Server Error.